# How to proxy a websocket properly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy, frontend

I'm having trouble proxies websocket using `http-proxy-middleware`. The error I got was `Websocket connection to https://api.dsm-staging.test.site failed`.
Here's the code I'm using in express :

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require("http-proxy-middleware");

const options = {
  target: "https://api.dsm-staging.test.site",
  changeOrigin: true,
  ws: true,
};

const proxy = createProxyMiddleware(options);
app.use("/v1/*", proxy);
```

This is my code in front end :

```
this.socket = io("https://api.dsm-staging.app.test.site", {
        reconnectionAttempts: 5,
        reconnectionDelayMax: 10000,
        extraHeaders: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
        transports: ["websocket"],
 });

 this.socket.on("connect", () => {
    console.log(this.socket.connected);
  });
```

Comment: Surely the target would need to be `wss://api.dsm-staging.test.site`, not `https`?

Comment: I have used both. But all not works